# Excel User Form, Previous Button

Tags: excel

I have an excel user form for data entry, at the moment the form functions so that users can add data. I would like to add a previous,next, first and last case button so that users can make edits via the form. The code I used for the form was derived from this website: http://www.contextures.com/xluserform02.html

If someone could describe how to add those command buttons to that form I would be very appreciative!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a tutorial on my site that almost does what you want.

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/09/linking-userforms-and-worksheets-part-v/

It uses a scrollbar instead of buttons, but you may be able to adapt it.  The basic steps are

Load the current row data into the form
Store the current row
When a button is pushed, change the stored row (to +1, -1, the first row, or the last row)
Load the new row's data

Then you have to have code that determines if the current record has been changed.  If it has, you have to write the changes or give the user the option to write or discard.

Also, you may want to disable the First and Previous buttons if the user is on the first record.  Similar for Last and Next and the last row.

The tutorial on my site has all that code and a downloadable workbook that you can follow along with.  Good luck.